unable to run vmware 17.5.2 after installation
after installation, upon first run, VMware starts 'VMWare Kernel Module Updater'. while trying to install/ update the requested modules, it failed. some relevant information are as follows.
VMware version is 17.5.2
OS is Ubuntu 24.04 LTS 
kernel is 6.8.0-39-generic
gcc version is 13.2.0
build-essential is installed

including an excerpt (grep -i 'failed ' /tmp/vmware-username/vmware-368262.log) of the error log below for reference.
2024-07-27T19:43:04.913Z In(05) host-368262 Failed to find /lib/modules/6.8.0-39-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2024-07-27T19:43:05.325Z In(05) host-368262 Failed to find /lib/modules/6.8.0-39-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2024-07-27T19:43:05.706Z In(05) host-368262 Failed to find /lib/modules/6.8.0-39-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2024-07-27T19:43:05.730Z In(05) host-368262 Failed to find /lib/modules/6.8.0-39-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2024-07-27T19:43:09.508Z In(05) host-368262 Failed to find /lib/modules/6.8.0-39-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2024-07-27T19:48:43.381Z In(05) host-368262 Failed to find /lib/modules/6.8.0-39-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2024-07-27T19:49:17.381Z In(05) host-368262 Failed to find /lib/modules/6.8.0-39-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2024-07-27T19:49:50.861Z In(05) host-368262 Failed to find /lib/modules/6.8.0-39-generic/build/include/linux/version.h

PS. encountered similar errors with older versions too (17.5). requesting for a solution or confirmation if i have to switch to virtualbox for the time being.
thank you

Open the link. It will help you. https://thelinuxforum.com/articles/969-how-to-compile-the-vmware-workstation-pro-kernel-modules-on-ubuntu-debian

It is the same with Ubuntu 22.04, I don't know how it is possible for a big software company like his ...
I found a working solution here :  https://nwgat.ninja/quick-easy-vmware-workstation-pro-on-ubuntu-24-04/
Fix the kernel drivers (17.5.1 is the same as 17.5.2)
wget https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules/archive/workstation-17.5.1.tar.gz
tar -xzf workstation-17.5.1.tar.gz && cd vmware-host-modules-workstation-17.5.1
tar -cf vmmon.tar vmmon-only && tar -cf vmnet.tar vmnet-only
sudo cp -v vmmon.tar vmnet.tar /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-al

Have a good day

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

hi, david, already followed this way, and setup/ run vmware successfully. albeit, i waited for a long time for an official fix. unfortunately, you and i, we both were unable to find any. thanks for the assistance.

I followed this and managed to fix my problem (which was that uninstalling VMWare Player 17.5.2 and installing back the previous version did not remove what failed as it was trying to update, thus being stuck with the failed-update problem even when trying to run the previous freshly-installed version.)
